# How to speed up drawing process of output from .tflite model

Tags: performance, android, kotlin

I have piece of code where I draw  output from model pixel by pixel:

```
fun draw(
        canvas: Canvas) {
        val rotated = sensorOrientation % 180 == 90
        var rotatedW = frameWidth;
        var rotatedH = frameHeight;
        if(rotated) {
            rotatedW = frameHeight
            rotatedH = frameWidth
        }

        val multiplier =
            min(
                canvas.height.toFloat() / rotatedH.toFloat(),
                canvas.width.toFloat() / rotatedW.toFloat()
            )
        val w = (rotatedW * multiplier).toInt()
        val h = (rotatedH * multiplier).toInt()

        results?.let {
            var pos: Int
            val xw = w / 256f
            val xh = h / 256f
            val rectF = RectF()
            for (y in 0 until 256) {
                for (x in 0 until 256) {
                    pos = getIndexOfMax(results!![0][y][x])
                    if (pos > 0) {
                        val vertical = y / 256f * h
                        val horizontal = x / 256f * w
                        rectF.left = horizontal - xw
                        rectF.top = vertical - xh
                        rectF.right = horizontal + xw
                        rectF.bottom = vertical + xh
                        canvas.drawRect(rectF, boxPaint)
                    }
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However this works really slow. Nested `for` is probably one of the main issues here. I don't know how can I speed it up. As you can see both counters are necessary here because I need to get certain field from `results`. I've heard that Bitmap uasage instead of `Canvas` would be partial solution because I am able to get certain pixels but I don't really know how to use it right. Method `draw()` is called here inside `MainActivity`:

```
trackingOverlay.addCallback(
            object : OverlayView.DrawCallback {
                override fun drawCallback(canvas: Canvas?) = tracker.draw(canvas!!)
            }
        )
```

And the `trackingOverlay` is an instance of `OverlayView` class which inherits from `View`:

```
class OverlayView(ctx: Context, attr: AttributeSet) : View(ctx, attr) {

    private val callbacks: MutableList<DrawCallback> =
        LinkedList()

    fun addCallback(callback: DrawCallback) { callbacks.add(callback) }

    @Synchronized
    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        for (callback in callbacks) {
            callback.drawCallback(canvas)
        }
    }

    interface DrawCallback {
        fun drawCallback(canvas: Canvas?)
    }
}
```

I've tried creating `Bitmap` before draw (to reuse it) and then use `canvas.drawBitmap()` but it needs transformation `Matrix` to fill whole screen, otherwise it covers only small chunk of it and even then I haven't noticed any performance increase.

**EDIT**
That's how `getIndexOfMax()` looks like:

```
private fun getIndexOfMax(array: FloatArray): Int {
        if (array.isEmpty()) return -1
        return when {
            array[0] > array[1] -> 0
            else -> 1
        }
    }
```

Results is 4 dim `Array` of `Float`

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Introduce coroutines in your code.

### Analysis

It is difficult to optimize a code, where multiple parts are missing, like:

- what does `getIndexOfMax` do? Maybe this is the bottleneck
- How do `results` look like? Arrays? Maps? HashMaps?

I found also some strange code parts, like:

- Why `results?.let {`? This can be removed completely.
- `var pos: Int` should be moved inside the inner loop and made a `val`

### Suggestion

I have too little context and I'm not familiar with Android, so the only thing I can suggest is [using coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html). My Example:

```kotlin
suspend fun draw(canvas: Canvas) = coroutineScope {
    val rotated = sensorOrientation % 180 == 90
    var rotatedW = frameWidth;
    var rotatedH = frameHeight;
    if (rotated) {
        rotatedW = frameHeight
        rotatedH = frameWidth
    }

    val multiplier =
        min(
            canvas.height.toFloat() / rotatedH.toFloat(),
            canvas.width.toFloat() / rotatedW.toFloat()
        )
    val w = (rotatedW * multiplier).toInt()
    val h = (rotatedH * multiplier).toInt()
    
    val xw = w / 256f
    val xh = h / 256f
    val rectF = RectF()
    for (y in 0 until 256) {
        for (x in 0 until 256) {
            launch {   // <-----
                val pos = getIndexOfMax(results!![0][y][x])
                if (pos > 0) {
                    val vertical = y / 256f * h
                    val horizontal = x / 256f * w
                    rectF.left = horizontal - xw
                    rectF.top = vertical - xh
                    rectF.right = horizontal + xw
                    rectF.bottom = vertical + xh
                    canvas.drawRect(rectF, boxPaint)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made edit to my question. Instead of making `index of max` I can just get value of `array[1]` and check if  pos > 0.6 (or 0.7)